# Get millisecond data from cassandra timestamp column

Tags: python, cassandra, timestamp

I am having a timestamp column in my cassandra table. The time is calculated with millisecond, the same is converted to long format and is being inserted in to the db

so the time value will be like 1400262790567 when i insert the data in to the db.

I am retrieving the same using python

```
query = select id, tsvalue from <tablename>
cursor.execute(query)
```

Once the data is retrieved and convered to long as below

```
long(time.mktime(tsvalue.timetuple()) * 1000)
```

the millisecond is not properly retrieved, the data that i got here is something like 1400262790000. This causes me not to retrieve correct row in my subsequent queries. How can we get the exact value in miliseconds precision.

Comment: How is your tsvalue being constructed? You are probably losing precision somewhere.

Comment: Richard, in our application we are storing value from java and the same is calculated as new java.sql.Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())

Comment: You can double check what's the value that is actually stored using either `cqlsh` or DevCenter. My gut feeling though is that precision is lost on the write.

Comment: This is my mistake. Sorry. The data i got but the conversion to millisecond in python created the issue. I use python 2.6 hence i try to get the miliisec since epoch using (delta.microseconds + (delta.seconds + delta.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6 and got wrong value. I cross checked by having python 2.7 in path and tryied using timedelta.total_seconds that got me correct value. Sorry for posting wrong question